# Creating merged CSV from two separate files, matching by unique column

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, merge, element

I have two csv datafiles, in which each row has a 100% unique element (Note the rows are not in the same order)  e.g.

#### CSV1

```
title1,title2,title3,UniqueElment,title4,title5
data,data,data,dasasd1245,data,data
data,data,data,dasasd1395,data,data
data,data,data,dasasd2594,data,data
data,data,data,dasasd9587,data,data
```

#### CSV2

```
titlea,titleb,titlec,titled,titlee,titlef,UniqueElment,titleg,titleh,titlei
text,text,text,text,text,text,dasasd1245,text,text,data
text,text,text,text,text,text,dasasd2594,text,text,data
text,text,text,text,text,text,dasasd1395,text,text,data
text,text,text,text,text,text,dasasd9587,text,text,data
```

#### Desired output:

```
title1,title2,title3,UniqueElment,title4,title5,titlea,titleb,titlec,titled,titlee,titlef,UniqueElment,titleg,titleh,titlei
data,data,data,dasasd1245,data,data,text,text,text,text,text,text,dasasd1245,text,text,data
data,data,data,dasasd1395,data,data,text,text,text,text,text,text,dasasd1395,text,text,data
data,data,data,dasasd2594,data,data,text,text,text,text,text,text,dasasd2594,text,text,data
data,data,data,dasasd9587,data,data,text,text,text,text,text,text,dasasd9587,text,text,data
```

I need to create a final CSV, where the data from both csvs is merged together based on matching the UniqueElement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Someone will probably write a `csv`-based answer, so I'll give the [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org) approach for comparison:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("file1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("file2.csv")
merged = df1.merge(df2, on="UniqueElment")
merged.to_csv("merged.csv", index=False)
```

which produces

```
$ cat merged.csv 
title1,title2,title3,UniqueElment,title4,title5,titlea,titleb,titlec,titled,titlee,titlef,titleg,titleh,titlei
data,data,data,dasasd1245,data,data,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,data
data,data,data,dasasd1395,data,data,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,data
data,data,data,dasasd2594,data,data,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,data
data,data,data,dasasd9587,data,data,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,data
```

If, as @beroe notes, you want the redundant `UniqueElment` column, that's easy enough too -- we'll just sort both to make sure they're in the same order and then concatenate them:

```
df1 = df1.sort("UniqueElment").reset_index(drop=True)
df2 = df2.sort("UniqueElment").reset_index(drop=True)
merged = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

Alternatively, we could have set the indexes to `UniqueElment` and merged, etc., which would be a little more robust against errors in the data.  The point is, that manipulations like this only take a few lines or so.

Comment: Very nice. Not sure if they really wanted to repeat `UniqueElment` in the output or not...

Comment: @beroe: true enough.  Added a variant in the case the OP wants that.

Comment: Ideally I wouldnt want Unique elemnt in the output, but I thought It might make it a significantly more complex task to not include it?

Comment: @SMNALLY: if you wanted to get rid of the column, all you'd need to do is `del merged['UniqueElment']` after doing the merge.